# how to calculate the area of Geohash?

Tags: geography, geohashing

I known the area of geohash(precision is 5)is 10 square kilometres. But I want to know the area of geohash(precision is 4) and I dont't know how to calculate. I read the wiki about Geohash, but I still get confused.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash

Answer (score 1):

The following the approx area for the specified precision.

Geohash length  Cell width  Cell height

1   ≤ 5,000km   ×   5,000km

2   ≤ 1,250km   ×   625km

3   ≤ 156km     ×   156km

4   ≤ 39.1km    ×   19.5km

5   ≤ 4.89km    ×   4.89km

6   ≤ 1.22km    ×   0.61km

7   ≤ 153m  ×   153m

8   ≤ 38.2m     ×   19.1m

9   ≤ 4.77m     ×   4.77m

10  ≤ 1.19m     ×   0.596m

11  ≤ 149mm     ×   149mm

12  ≤ 37.2mm    ×   18.6mm

More info: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html